# Cordova App - Dropdown instant close

Tags: android, cordova, dropdown, fastclick

I've read some posts ([github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6992), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173272/300ms-delay-removal-using-fastclick-js-vs-using-ontouchstart/27236628#27236628), etc.) about this kind of issue, but I don't really get the right solution.

I'm creating a Cordova app* and I'm testing it on an Android 4.3 and I've some issue with the dropdown ( html tag). When I touch the select the option list open and close instantly.

The problem seems to come from fastclick.js cause when I remove it, it works ok but it looks not really good (as you know).

What could you advice me to do to fix it ?

Big thanks.

---

Code Sample :

```
onDeviceReady: function() {             
    // Fixing the Status Bar Issue on iOS7
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView( false );
    StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');
    StatusBar.styleDefault();

    // Avoiding the 300ms Click Delay
    //FastClick.attach(document.body);
    [...]
}
```

---

App details :

- Base on the Apache Cordova Tutorial
- Ratchet Components
- Replace content with jQuery

Comment: Have you added debugger; tags and stepped through your code? I also ran into some issues when coding my one hybrid app. Use Chrome, open dev console (F12) then step through the code and the answer to what is failing/not running will be revealed.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I don't have debugger on the mobile device but on Chrome there is no error. Do you think another JS error (somewhere) could make it happen ?

Comment: Hmm it could very well be.. Hard to say without the code

Comment: Also, there is no issue in Chrome, only on the mobile device.

Comment: You use chrome to debug a web app on your mobile device - then you can pick up what the errors are etc.

Comment: Yep, that's how I do. I've no JS error anywere with Chrome...pretty weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm, it was due to Fastclick. I added the needsclick class on my SELECT tags and it fixed the issue.

Thanks for your time.

E.