# jQuery mousedown on mobile delayed

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I'm trying to fire some code as soon as an element starts being pressed using jQuery's `mousedown` function, but it's always delayed by about half a second or so. I tried `on("touchstart", ... )` but that never even fired the event ever. How do I get the event to fire straight away? I'm testing it on an Android. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [300ms delay removal: using fastclick.js vs using ontouchstart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173272/300ms-delay-removal-using-fastclick-js-vs-using-ontouchstart)

Answer (score -1):

jQuery Mobile's "tap"

```
$("p").on("tap",function(){...});
```

Comment: is your jQuery is

Comment: Is my jQuery is what?

Comment: to press Enter button was a bad idea. I mean, do you really use jQuery Mobile, not usual jQuery? What version?

Comment: I'm just using normal jquery

Comment: Please use normal jQuery Mobile at mobile platforms, it can solve many problems.

Comment: Mysterious puzzle